# When are software questions ok?

Tags: discussion

I'm confused; we closed a request for a review of [Switch Poker on Android](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/775/is-the-switch-poker-android-app-any-good) but we left open the question asking if anyone knows if [Poker Academy Pro](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/765/poker-academy-pro-or-an-alternative) is available. They are both software questions and, to Toby's comment, neither deals with the "how of playing" of poker.

Why is the "review of Switch" a bad question and the "can anyone find Poker Academy" not?

Answer (score 2):

This is, of course, my opinion. If I'm not thinking straight make sure to tell me why. I think the differences in the questions are subtle but important.

The android question to me is asking about the app only, and if the app is any good at replicating the poker experience. The question won't help anyone play better poker. I thought that's what this site was for. It may as well be asking is X app good for Y. Thats about as far as the scope of the question goes. If you try to extend the X...Y reasoning you end up talking more software (e.g. "Good Functionality", "Nice UI", "Fast & Responsive"). Perhaps if he'd asked what the best app for android is, without preference, it may not have seemed so narrow to me. Similar to [this](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/501/is-there-any-poker-online-software-which-run-on-linux) or [this](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/675/what-software-to-use-when-playing-online).

The Poker Academy (PA) question IMO is different. Im actually glad you asked this because to be honest, I wasn't sure why I saw them differently until now. PA is/was a *learning* tool and not just a mechanistic client to play poker...it teaches. There is a part of the question in which the questioner asks for alternatives. Specifically, "...poker training software". Those questions have had a decent response on this site so far.

I suppose it's arguable that all clients are training software of some type if you play enough, but PA actually uses a combination of analysis tools for that job where a basic mechanistic client will not. Like I said before, isn't learning to play better poker what this site is for. An open question relating to that seems reasonable, a closed question about one brand of poker client doesn't IMO.

Whereas the android question will elicit a yes/no response and maybe some alternative suggestions, it's akin to having a discussion on whether Pokerstars is better than Full Tilt is better than iPoker, etc. A *pure* software discussion. At least people could give an answer based on how *well* they were taught by PA and not just if they liked using it.

Asking for alternatives to PA will elicit some responses about teaching methodology and effectiveness of the tools at improving your game.

I hope this didn't come off as vague or ranty, It's not my intention. I just wanted to state what I thought. By all means if you can offer some counter arguments then I could re-open it, otherwise it'll stay closed.

Also, When I look at the FAQ description of poker.se it seems pretty broad and vague. https://poker.stackexchange.com/faq#questions. perhaps it could be more specific to encompass these grey areas, in whatever direction the community sees fit. It is editable!

Comment: After reading your two linked questions, I'm really confused. Asking for Linux or "Any" poker client is ok, asking about a specific client is not? Had our Android guy asked for "Clients for Android" it'd have been ok? I'm struggling with the difference between PA and this App. They're both /software/, one is a Teaching tool and the other is a practice tool (when you get down to it). I think it should be okay to ask the community if a given client is any good, especially AIs, as this SE is the area where people should know the answer. "Stupid X always bluffs, waste of $$" etc.

Comment: Did you ever use PA? If not, it's a simulator. Users can play AI opponents in LHE & NLHE in cash and tournament varieties. Switch is a pure client, with *only* human opponents. If narrow questions about individual poker clients are acceptable as you'd suggest then every client that exists will eventually get its own thread, including every update they get...

Comment: Asking if an AI is any good is very different from asking for opinions on clients. The other questions about LAN, Linux, PA, software to manage hand histories, are related to people having problems playing poker. Whether they have a need for analysis or a client, *any* client. These questions ask for a solution, not an opinion. Expertise in an opinion is great, so how does the switch question elicit that? I admit it's not clear cut, it's somewhat subjective. What's a good question, what isn't. I think if I wanted a review I'd go to CNET or something.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better in chat! ;)

Comment: The quotation was meant as an example opinion of a generic AI. I'm not suggesting anything; I'm asking what would have made the question that was closed *valid* so I can help moderate.

Comment: continued in chat...

Answer (score 0):

I was kind of confused by that too, so I went with "ignore it." Both questions seem acceptable to me.